# A simple proof about graphs.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, group-isomorphism

Let's have distinct vertices a,b,c,d,e,f of a graph. There are automorphisms consisting of two transpositions: (a/b)(c/d) is an automorphism, (c/d)(e/f) is an automorphism. Then a single transposition (c/d) must be an automorphism, too.

What would be the most clear way to prove it? I hope it holds ...

Comment: What if it wasn't an automorphism? What would that mean? Prove by contradiction.

Comment: Automorphism of a graph is a bijective function, that maps each vertex to another vertex, such that when you rename vertices by that function, you would get the same graph.

Comment: So, what does it mean if $(c/d)$ is not an automorphism?

Comment: That after replacing c with d and d with c, you get the same graph.

Comment: E.g. when you have a complete graph or an empty graph on N vertices, there are N! automorphisms. On a cycle of the length N, there are N automorphisms. The identity is always an automorphism.

Comment: No, what does it mean if it is *not* an automorphism.

Comment: Here's a hint: show that $c$ and $d$ have exactly the same neighbours in $\{a,b,e,f\}$. This will show that $(c~d)$ is an automorphism. To see this, pick an edge between those two sets, say $\{a,c\}$, and apply the two starting automorphisms repeatedly.

Comment: @verret thanks! And do you thing it also holds, when there is a common vertex, e.g. $b = f$ ?